# Conda environment being installed in wrong folder?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

When i open anaconda prompt it runs from: C\Users\myname

i run `conda create --name pytest`

this successfuly installs pytest.

I then open pycharm anaconda and look in my folder: `C\Users\myname\Anaconda3\envs` and it is not there..

However it is actually installed in a different folder:

```
C:\projects\tgs\myname\condapv\envs\pytest\python.exe
```

i have no idea why it is doing this shouldn't it be installing the environment in the anaconda3 file? how can i get it to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve what you are experiencing is to setup a different envs_dirs in the .condarc file, see: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs.

So you might want to check this via

`conda config --show-sources`

Also try

`conda info` for further insights

Comment: Or more precisely, `conda config --show envs_dirs`, and probably need to run `conda config --remove envs_dirs "C:\projects\tgs\myname\condapv\envs"`.